# Разрешение экрана не совпадает заявленным

Tags: java, android

Как-то случайно попал мне в руки супер телефон Sony Xperia XZ Premium (G8142). Но, при попытке потестить своё приложение, наблюдаю "поехавшую" разметку. Выясняется, что размеры экрана, которые я вычисляю так,

`log(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().toString());`

получаю 1776х1080

`// DisplayMetrics{density=3.0, width=1080, height=1776, scaledDensity=3.0, xdpi=403.41177, ydpi=403.04132}}`,

не такие как по паспорту (3840x2160).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно получить размер экрана в пикселях?

Comment: На некоторых телефонах можно менять разрешение экрана в настройках. Возможно и на этом так.

Comment: Скриншот делается правильный - 7.5 МБ  и 3840x2160px. Но, серый фон моего аппа, смотрится под лупой отвратительно. Если это симуляция более низкого разрешения, то сделано паршиво ...

Answer (score 3):

Телефон "прикидывается" FullHD, вот тут
https://www.slashgear.com/run-the-xperia-xz-premium-in-4k-all-the-time-with-this-trick-05490607/

пишут почему так:

> The UI itself is stuck at 1080p, however. This is to prevent the screen from eating all that precious battery minutes.

И как переключить в 4К.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, немного прояснилось. Но, есть ли способ, всё-таки узнать реальное разрешение экрана? Вычисление через  ydpi xdpi  не дают правильного результата.

Comment: Погоняйте старый добрый System Info на нем, может найдете зацепку откуда это можно вытянуть. Потому что стандартно скорее всего нет, система же тоже "верит" что он FullHD.